# Groebner basis and prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal in a polynomial ring $P = K[x,y_1,\dots,y_n]$ and assume that $I \cap K[x]\neq (0)$. Let $>$ be an elimination ordering for $\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ and $G$ is a Groebner basis for $I$ with respect to $>$.

1. Why $G\cap K[x]$ is in fact a single polynomial f?

edit: yes I agree $G \cap K$ is also a Grobner
2. And why if $I$ is prime ideal, then $f$ is irreducible?

edit2: $I \cap k[x]$ is a nontrivial prime ideal, so it is maximal, and therefore $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: I'm guessing that's supposed to be $I \cap K[x] \neq (0)$.  Because if $I \cap K \neq 0$, then $I$ contains a nonzero element of $K$, which is a unit, so $I = K[x,y_1, \ldots, y_n]$.

Comment: That is a typo, thank you. I missed.

Comment: $G\cap K[X]$ is a groebner basis for the intersection ideal, by the theory on elimination. How are Groebner bases for ideeals in the PID $k[x]$? Also, if $I$ is prime so is its intersection with $k[x]$, as you can easily check.

Comment: I did, I can bring it back. But it looks like it been resolved on the end (this might take a while I check my history).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, for the second part, is it because $I \cap k[x]$ is prime, so it is maximal in the poly nominal ring an therefore it is irreducible.?